# Show 5 Results from foreach loop in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, foreach

Hi I want to do some pagination with my array with my foreach loop so I did this:

```
$page = 0;
$i = 0;
foreach($time as $indTime){
    if($i % 5 == 0){
        $page++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

So basically the first 5 result page = 1 the next 5 page=2 the next 5 page = 3 and so on. Now Im using twitter bootstrap and I want to use the pagination component which is basically links with << 1 2 3 4 5 >> to click on your page. What I need is when you click on 1, it shows every result from the foreach loop where $page = 1 when I click 2, $page = 2 etc. Anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: Is  << 1 2 3 4 5 >> displaying properly?

Comment: yea i didnt show the code for that because its unimportant to my question though its just links like  <li><a href="#" >1</a></li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Route for the resource

You have to create routes for the pagination like: `example.com/times/2` where `2` will be the page number, so you can use them in your links `<a href="example.com/times/2">`. Then [get the number from the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/php-get-the-full-url). Alternatively you can just pass the number as a GET or POST parameter.

### Validate the number

You cannot trust user input, so check if the given number is valid.

### Print the page

Finally just compare the page with the given/selected page number and print the items.

```
$time = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

$page_selected = 2;
$page = 1;
$i = 1;
foreach ($time as $indTime) {
    if ($page == $page_selected) {
      echo $indTime;
      echo ' ';
    }
    if ($i % 5 == 0) {
        $page++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

This will print the items of the second page: `6 7 8 9 10`.